# Is there a wordpress template like this

Tags: templates

can wordpress do this: https://reverb.com/news/12-pro-guitarists-share-the-first-riffs-they-ever-learned?utm_campaign=c40373e131-rn171001_sunday_content&utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_term=0_5889ed6702-c40373e131-62804885

and if so, where do i find the template?

thanks

andy

Answer (score 1):

Yes WordPress can do this, easily. Try www.themeforest.net

Although I'm pretty sure this is off topic so your question may get down voted.